# how to stop pyttsx3 in middle of speech?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pyttsx, pyttsx3

I want to stop pyttsx3. I tried killing multiprocess but then the response time gets slow I dont know why. Here is the code:

```
import pyttsx3
from multiprocessing import Process

def speakfunc(audio):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
    engine.setProperty('rate', 140)
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()



def speak(audio):
    p = Process(target=speakfunc, args=(audio,))
    p.start()

    while p.is_alive():
         if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
             p.terminate()
         else:
             continue
    p.join()
```

Are there any option or alternative to stop speech in middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a try, except statement as in this case when `Ctrl + C` is pressed it is going to terminate the process.

```
def speak(audio):
    try:
        p = Process(target=speakfunc, args=(audio,))
        p.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        p.terminate()

    p.join()
```

Comment: hey, I tried it but pyttsx is not stoping in middle. It is not taking Ctrl + C in middle of speech. And the delay is still there :(

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
#abunchoflines
except('''nameoferror'''):
#anotherbunchoflines
```

Is equal to saying "try (#abunchoflines), if there is an error raised with the name of error((occasionally, it can be blank, interpreting 'all errors')), execute (#anotherbunchoflines)." not so handy since `ctrl+c` typically is equal to `sys. exit(0)`, or even `os._exit(0)`. There is a `pynput` module, specifically, `pynput.keyboard` that does the trick with multi-(threading/processing). The sub-categories? `Key` and `Listener`.

Sample(without multi-(threading/processing)):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
def show(key):
    print('\nYou Entered {0}'.format( key))
    if key == Key.delete:#delete key pressed
    return False#stop listener
while 1:#collect events until released
    with Listener(on_press = show) as listener:
         listener.join()
```